# Lie algebra of $SO(V)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

As picture below ,why the Lie algebra of $SO(V)$ is obtained by differentiating the relation $\langle Av,A\omega \rangle =\langle v,\omega\rangle$ ?

And how to calculate the differentiating of $\langle Av,A\omega \rangle =\langle v,\omega\rangle$ ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Does this help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21837/how-do-you-find-the-lie-algebra-of-a-lie-group-in-practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof in [synthetic differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_differential_geometry) using infinitesimals. You can easily convert the proof into a standard one using limits, and derivatives, but this method is perfectly valid (via the embedding of smooth manifolds into the Dubuc topos, for instance), and is a bit more intuitive, in my opinion.

Anyway, let $\epsilon$ be a nilsquare infinitesimal (i.e. $\epsilon^2$=0). A matrix $X \in \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ belongs to $\mathfrak{o}(V)$ if and only if $I + \epsilon X \in O(V)$. We know this matrix is already in $GL(V)$, so we just need to ensure that it preserves the inner product. Well this is straightforward:
\begin{align}
\langle (I + \epsilon X)v, (I + \epsilon X)w 
\rangle & = \langle v , w \rangle + \epsilon \langle Xv, w 
\rangle + \epsilon \langle v, Xw 
\rangle + \epsilon^2 \langle Xv, Xw 
\rangle \\
&  = \langle v , w \rangle + \epsilon \langle Xv, w 
\rangle + \epsilon \langle v, Xw 
\rangle
\end{align}
We have just expanded and used $\epsilon^2=0$ to eliminate the last term. Thus, it is easy to see that $I + \epsilon X \in O(V)$, and hence $X \in \mathfrak{o}(V)$, if and only if $$\langle Xv, w 
\rangle + \langle v, Xw 
\rangle = 0.$$

Comment: I can't understand nilsquare infinitesimal.

Comment: It's the same idea as taking a first order Taylor approximation.